# Is there a better way to speed up Pandas for reading csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv

OS: macOS High Sierra, ver 10.13.1
Python 3.6 in Xcode

I am reading a csv file using both pandas and conventional python's csv module. Apparently, csv module is significantly faster than pandas. I understand pandas does NaN checks, but I have two questions: (i) Is there a way to speed up pandas? (ii) Is there a downside of using python's csv module over pandas?

My code:

```
def read_pd():
    path=os.getcwd()
    filename="Sen_01_sample.csv"
    filePathname=path +"/"+filename
    #print('reading...')
    data=pd.read_csv(filePathname,nrows=11,engine="c",skiprows=0)
    #print('read')

def read_csv():
    path=os.getcwd()
    filename="Sen_01_sample.csv"
    filePathname=path+"/"+filename
    with open(filePathname,mode='r') as csvfile:
        csvread=csv.reader(csvfile)
        col_count=len(next(csvread))
        row_count = sum(1 for row in csvread)
        #print(row_count)

        #print(col_count)
        csvfile.seek(0)
        data=np.zeros((row_count-1,col_count-5),dtype=np.float32)
        row=0
        line_count=0
        for rows in csvread:
            if line_count ==0:
                dummy=0
            else:
                data[row]=np.array(rows[4:-1],dtype=np.float32)
                #print (data[row][-1])
            line_count+=1
```

Timing results:

```
Time to read a csv file from Pandas 130.997ms.
Time to read a csv file using Python's native csv module 15.448ms.
Python csv module reads file at 11.79% of the time taken by Pandas.
```

Comment: Of course `pandas.read_csv` takes longer. It has to read lines/delimiters, scan and determine data types, map values to data frame structure, build index, and other meta work. Also your latter example builds a numpy array not pandas data frame. Try [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: so, in simple cases , with known data types, csv.reader() will be a good choice if performance is critical, isn't it?

Comment: Once again, since all your data types is numeric and you need to build a numpy array, try `numpy.loadtxt`. Pandas data frames are more extensive than numpy arrays with more properties and attributes.